# Eclipselink NPE on find

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

When issuing a simple "find" operation to an entity, Eclipselink throws a NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.CMP3Policy.createPrimaryKeyFromId(CMP3Policy.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.findInternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:599)
```

The entity uses multitenancy with a table-per-tenant strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are setting the tenant property on the entity manager, like so:

```
String tenant = // ...
EntityManager em = // ...
em.setProperty(PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT, tenant);
```

Comment: do you use a **persistence.xml** file ?

Comment: Yes, but the tenant property depends on data from the request (it is dynamic).